# bitbucket pipeline image from variable

Tags: yaml, bitbucket-pipelines

I have this section in my bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
      image: 
        name: eu.gcr.io/$GCLOUD_PROJECT/some-name-here
        username: _json_key
        password: '$GCLOUD_API_KEYFILE'
```

It fails because the image name contains a variable, is there a workaround for that or must the image name be hardcoded in the bitbucket-pipelines.yml ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use variables in the Docker image names.

There is an [open Jira issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-13014) with this feature request created back in 2016, and at the time of writing it's still 'gathering interest'.